# Stuck on Transferring Your Information

Tags: macbook-pro, migration-assistant

I have a brand new MacBook Pro. I started a migration from a time machine backup...it has now been stuck on “about a minute remaining “ for 8+ hours. How does one remedy this?
[image]

Comment: This may or may not be the case here, however, at the last part of any macOS setup there's a point beyond which it can no longer measure how long the last step may take. I'd hang on at least overnight & see if it's just taking its time about it. It may error or it may complete, but I'd let patience rule for a while longer. Plug it into the mains & leave the lid open.

Comment: I let it go for a bit, with no change. I pulled the plug and rebooted and all is well. Thx.